# Python List Comprehenion Get JSON Values

Tags: python, json, list-comprehension

I have a JSON like:

```py
data = [
    {"word": "Hi", "lang": "en"},
    {"word": "Bonjour", "lang": "fr"},
    ...
]
```

I want to execute a function (named `db.insertIntoSwearWords`) for each key-value pair.
This is what I've done so far

```py
words = [item['word'] for item in data]
langs = [item['lang'] for item in data]
res = [db.insertIntoSwearWords(words[i], langs[i]) for i in range(len(words))]
result = [{'word': words[i], 'result': res[i]} for i in range(len(words))]
print(jsonify(result))
```

which gives me:

```py
[
    {"result": true, "word": "Hi"},
    {"result": true, "word": "Bonjour"},
    ...
]
```

**MY PROBLEM:**
Just wondering if there is any better way to write this program with fewer lines. I'm not a fan of `for i in range()` really. I'm just curious how can I do the list comprehension with `for word, lang in item` syntax.

Comment: Checkout [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: What's the point of the words and langs lists? You could `zip` them to save iterating over a range, but why not just e.g. `result = [{"word": d["word"], result: db.insertIntoSwearWords(d["word"], d["lang"])} for d in data}`.

Comment: Since it seems you have working code and are looking for general improvements, this appears to more appropriate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) – be sure to check their [question guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) first, though.

Comment: Extracting two separate lists of variables isn't helpful since they later get recombined back into their original pairs at the point they're fed into the function. I was thinking zip as well, but it's not necessary given the task. [edit] Ahh, which is precisely the point @jonrsharpe makes above with more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function.
For example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> c = [(i, j) for i, j in zip(a, b)]
>>> c
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

Also, you can do

```
>>> list(zip(a, b))
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

Which gives the same result.

Comment: When you answer,please provide a specific (to the question) solution, a generic solution is not a good way to answer ;)

Comment: @azro thanks for pointing that out, I will be more specific in the future :)

Comment: What you're suggestion is I replace third line with `res = [db.insertIntoSwearWords(word, lang) for word,lang in zip(words,langs)]`, that's helpful. but still the code is ugly and I'm trying to write a neat code. Isn't there a better way than parsing word/lang separately and zipping them back?